# Appium Python: Should we always put assert when doing a hard assertion?

Tags: python, appium, python-appium

I'm just confused and I almost always see we put an `assert` before a hard assertion. In Appium, is it always necessary to put `assert`?

Both fails when the element being tested is not displayed:

`self.element().is_displayed()` versus `assert self.element().is_displayed()`